# Code completion for Spring security' and() method in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-security

When using Spring Security 3.2.1, why this compiles ok but IntelliJ 13 marks "formLogin" red?

```
http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
```

Can this be resolved so that i can auto complete nicely in IDE?

I think it is related to the fact that and() returns a H (generic) and IntelliJ cannot detect methods to auto-complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably connected with intellij issue:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118733